# Unable to sucessufly create an Gluon project whit Glisten Afterburner on Intelij

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon, gluon-mobile, gluon-desktop

I attempted to create a Gluon Mobile application whit the Glisten Afterburner framework on Intelij, however once i create it i cannot even launch it.

If i try to run the program i get the following error:
[image]

If i try to use scene builder in any of the fxml files:
[image]

My fxml code is the one generated by default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<View fx:id="primary" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gluon.attempt.views.PrimaryPresenter">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="15.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="label" text="%label.text.1" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" text="%button.text">
               <graphic>
                  <Icon content="LANGUAGE" />
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</View>
```

StackTrace:
[image]

ApplicationCode:

```
package com.gluon.attempt;

import com.gluon.attempt.views.AppViewManager;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Attempt extends MobileApplication {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        AppViewManager.registerViewsAndDrawer(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);


        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(Attempt.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't open FXML files with custom controls (you need to open it with Gluon Scene Builder), so that's not related to the error running the application. Post the stacktrace.

Comment: How do i post the stacktrace? Kind of new to gluon?

Comment: See the output of the gradle task `run`. Or run from a terminal: `./gradlew --info run`.

Comment: I updated the question, i hope it can be easier now to understand the problem.

Comment: While it'd be better if you post the stacktrace with text instead of a screenshot, it's clear enough to find the issue: You are running Java 9, aren't you? The Glisten-Afterburner and the jfxmobile plugin 1.3.10 are for Java 8. There is a template (Single project with Gluon VM) with plugin 2.0.8 intended for Java 9.

Comment: Yes im running whit java 9, i will instal java 8 and see if it works. Thanks.